# unable to apply a ttk theme to .toplevel()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-menu

I'm trying to rcreate a slasph screen which doubles as an about screen on a menu bar in tkinter and python 3.

so far I've read I should be using a `Toplevel()` method on the second `splash_root` but It justs send me the error that, `name 'Toplevel' is not defined`.

Have I missed something basic here or just misunderstood how `Toplevel()` works?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

def splash_screen():
   splash_root = Toplevel(root)
   splash_root.geometry("500x400")

   img_title = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("art/icons/random.png"))
   lbl_img_title = ttk.Label(splash_root,image=img_title)
   lbl_img_title.pack(side="top",pady=20)

   splash_label_by = ttk.Label(splash_root, text="name")
   splash_button = ttk.Button(splash_root, text="close", command=lambda: splash_root.destroy())

   splash_label_by.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
   splash_button.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10)

splash_screen()

root = ThemedTk(themebg=True)
root.set_theme('black')
root.title("splash")
root.geometry("500x500")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question:

```
#Toplevel(root) is not defined
tk.Toplevel(root) #will solve your Toplevel problem.
```

If you call
splash_screen()
before declaring root, root will be not defined and your code still wont work.

Comment: I've made some adjustments and moved the 'splash_root' and 'splash_root geometry()' into the main root window. and that has solved the error message but the theme is not inheriting from the root

Comment: With a little research I've found a comment: # Normal Tkinter.* widgets are not themed!
Here: [ttkthemes Example](https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html)

That means, you probably have to build an own Toplevel __init__ which calls the theme of the root.

Comment: Thanks I'll look that over